# IntelliJ "Cannot resolve symbol 'CottonClientScreen'" for fabricMC minecraft modding

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, minecraft-fabric

I have been trying to re-familiarize myself in Java and decided to tackle making a Minecraft mod as it seemed fairly simple.  I set up IntelliJ IDEA for Manjaro linux and set up my `build.gradle`.  Everything seemed to be working smoothly until I tried to add the dependency "CottonMC:LibGui" which is a dependency for making intuitive GUI's for Minecraft mods.  When I added the dependency to my project, I recieved the error, "Cannot resolve symbol 'CottonClientScreen'" which is a part of the LibGui dependency.  I feel as if this is likely a beginner mistake, but I have not been able to find a solution on the internet.

What I've tried:
Running `./gradlew genSources` after adding the dependency to my `repositories` and `dependencies` sections of my `build.gradle`
Restarting IntelliJ and clearing my cache
Searching for the dependency in IntelliJ using the "Generate Dependency" tool (the dependency did not come up even when I copied the exact link to it)

Files in Question:
`build.gradle` (trimmed to only contain relevent sections)

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name = "CottonMC"
        url = "https://server.bbkr.space/artifactory/libs-release"
    }
}

dependencies {
    minecraft "com.mojang:minecraft:${project.minecraft_version}"
    mappings "net.fabricmc:yarn:${project.yarn_mappings}:v2"
    modImplementation "net.fabricmc:fabric-loader:${project.loader_version}"

    modImplementation "net.fabricmc.fabric-api:fabric-api:${project.fabric_version}"

    modImplementation include("io.github.cottonmc:LibGui:6.3.0+1.19")
}
```

Implementation file:

```
import io.github.cottonmc.cotton.gui.GuiDescription;
import io.github.cottonmc.cotton.gui.client.CottonClientScreen;

public class screen extends CottonClientScreen {

}
```

Exact error:
[image]

Java Version

```
openjdk version "18.0.2" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2+0, mixed mode)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to click on `Reload All Gradle Projects` in Gradle tool window. (https://prnt.sc/Oh9K8eCDu9uT)

Comment: I have no idea how I may have missed something that simple in my research, but it worked, thank you!